# Python Networkx detecting loops/circles

Tags: python, loops, networkx

Given the following example:

[image]

Is there a possibilty to detect a loop in the network `(I1, I2,I3, C6, C7, I5)`?

I tried: `simple_cycles` → it works fine with 3 nodes, but not with more than 3.

I would need to detect the circle with all nodes and the "input" node `("I1")` and the "output" `("I3")`.

Comment: Do you have any code to show what you have tried to do?

Comment: (I1, I2,I3, C6, C7, I5) is not a loop, because your graph is directed. Do you still want to find the (I1, I2,I3, C6, C7, I5) loop anyway?

Comment: @FlavianHautbois yes - i need to find the loop. Any ideas?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I recreated your graph as such:

```
import networkx as nx

g = nx.DiGraph([('P', 'I0'), ('I0', 'I1'), ('I1', 'I2'),
                ('I2', 'I3'), ('I1', 'I5'), ('I5', 'C7'),
                ('C7', 'C6'), ('C6', 'I3'), ('I3', 'C9')])
```

You were searching for simple cycles but there is none in the above graph:

```
>>> list(nx.simple_cycles(g))
[]
```

so you have to search for cycles in the undirected graph. You have to cast your graph to an undirected graph. For undirected graphs, the `cycle_basis` function is what you seem to need:

```
>>> nx.cycle_basis(g.to_undirected())
[['I5', 'C7', 'C6', 'I3', 'I2', 'I1']]
```

Comment: How do I specify the starting vertex?

Answer (score -1):

Yes, if you use the method `nx.simple_cycles(G)`, you will get the cycle in the graph as a set of nodes that are in a cycle (as I've understudd it). For more info check [this](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.cycles.simple_cycles.html) out.

Comment: I've fixed the link